# How do I setup a stored procedure that can output data and then reuse that data to send an email

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am needing to the do the following:

Whenever a field changes in a specific row I need it to trigger a copy to a table (`dbo.StatusChange`), doing an insert of what was changed to what it changed too. I also need this date/time stamped.

Next I need that to trigger an email to send to 3 fields that are listed in that same row. I was told not to use triggers and instead a stored procedure. I want to set output variables, but don't know how to.

I have dbmail and am already aware of how to set this up and use it (already tested this part).

So whenever the field `[Site_Status]` is changed, I need it to fire a copy of the deleted and updated types to a new table called `[dbo.statuschange]`, deleted being listed under the `[previous]` column and the updated put into `[new]` column. This will also need to time stamp. I need to declare these variables as `@oldstatus` and `@newstatus`.

Next I need to declare the variable `@Reseller Email` (coming from table `[siteinformation.reselleremail]` (each record has a different email)  I have no idea if this is even right.

Comment: Show us what you already have.

Comment: Well, you were told not to use triggers and are expecting to trigger the stored procedure?

Comment: I guess I wasn't fully precise.  I am using info path, and whenever I have a Insert or Update to a record where the Site Status column is changed from let's say '